# How to add dot after two digit in text field on key up in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My text field value format is 00.00. If i enter 4 digit number(1234), my text field should be automatically adjust 12.34 format. How to achieve this action in javascript on keyup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
    <script>
function round_off(mystring){
//alert(mystring);
mystring=mystring.replace(/\./g,'');
mystring = mystring.substring(0, 4);

mystring1 = mystring.substring(0, 2);
mystring2 = mystring.substring(2, 4);

mystring2=""+mystring1+"."+mystring2+"";
//alert(mystring2);
if(mystring!="" && mystring.length>2){
document.getElementById("round_no").value=mystring2;
}

}



</script>

<input type="text" id="round_no" value="" maxlength="5" onkeyup="round_off(this.value)">
```

Comment: Its working fine on keyup. but keydown the value not removing properly. @Vikas

Answer (score 1):

Try RegEx:

```js
$(function() {
  $('input[type=text].two').on('input propertychange', function(e) {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/\D/g, '').replace(/(\d{2})(\d*)/, '$1.$2');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" autofocus='' class='two' />
<input type="text" class='two' />
```

Here, `.replace(/\D/g, '')` will give you only digits and `.replace(/(\d{2})(\d*)/, '$1.$2')` will split your value with dot separator

Answer (score 0):

Thats not how it works. if the format is 00.00 then it will just end up 1234.00

Comment: Is there any way to achieve this functionality? @Kimtho6

Answer (score 0):

this has already been handled here: 
    [How to print a number with commas as thousands separators in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript)

// for now
as provided by the chosen answer in the above link:
    replace (\d{3}) with 2,

but actually i would need to know more of what the actual goal is , why u want to format it that way, etc in order to give a complete (valid) answer. But just take a read in the link above

http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html <---